# Integrate Microsoft bot in a custom platform

Tags: authentication, botframework

I'm setting a chatbot for my custom platform. 
The chatbot needs to be integrated in the front as a component and recognize every platform's user by getting his access token from the front.
Using that access token the chatbot will be able to make API calls. 
Is it possible to do that with Microsoft Bot Framework. If it is true how to pass the access token from the front to the chatbot's backend ?

Comment: I answered your question fairly generally since I don't have details about what channel you're using. If you need more information, I'll need more details about what channel you're using and what you want the UX to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's three different ways you can approach this. Read the blog post, [Sign-In Experiences](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/08/28/sign-in-experiences/) for more details, but the gist of it is:

1. Pass the token through ChannelData

   - Any channel can receive immutable ChannelData that gets attached to an activity. You could use something like, `activity.ChannelData = new { Token = "xyz" }`
   - [This WebChat Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities) shows how you could attach that token to every message in the Web Chat Channel
   - [This issue comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/1564#issuecomment-458732245) may give you other ideas if you're using Web Chat
2. Use [Enhanced Direct Line Authentication](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/)

   - This associates a Direct Line user ID with the token
3. Use OAuth

   - You can use any OAuth provider and prompt them with a login card
   - The [Bot Authentication Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/18.bot-authentication) should help with that
   - [This guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv1%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth) will also help
   - Note: This may not be ideal for you since you want the bot to get the token passed from your platform, without the login step. I'm just adding it as an option.